# How to get last inserted and updated value without using identity column in SQL using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

How to get the last inserted and updated value in the result set from ASP.NET MVC? I am not maintaining the identity column in `Sal` table and maintaining the only primary key. Please give me an example.

Comment: Keep it in another table or in session on some where and get it from there. Update it whenever you update or insert the data.

Comment: Can you post `Sal` table schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add 2 new columns of datatype datetime in your table
First column to save createdDate timestamp and second to save last updated timestamp
you can set default for cratedDate column.
like => `alter yourtable add CreatedDate datetime default(getdate())`

For LastUpdate column, you need to set timestamp in every update query of {yourTable}

And to fetch last inserted :

```
select top 1 * from yourTable order by CreatedDate desc
```

to fetch last updated:

```
select top 1 * from yourTable order by LastUpdate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use Timestamps in table schema
and keep CREATED_DT
& UPDATED_DT seperate so you can keep track of changes

Answer (score 0):

select max(Emp_ID) from tbl_Employee